# Render jsf form in pdf

Tags: primefaces, pdf-generation, jsf-2.2

Hi I got a requirement where I have a pdf form to register for university. In this form you will need to input your personal details and all your qualifications. Instead of filling this form on paper , they want to do it online on web. 
So I will be using primefaces  5.3 and jsf 2.0 to build the form and save it in db using hibernate and spring. Now after saving the form, I should be able to generate the form on a pdf and keep the format the same as it was on paper. ( with dot line and small tables etc...) Do you know any pdf library that can do this? Normally i use itext for pdf but it's not possible to keep this format with itext.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many tools to do that, you can use **ireport** or **jasperreport** to build your reporting i advice you to use this tools, they work good with java

you can find here 
http://community.jaspersoft.com/project/jasperreports-library

http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/designing-report

http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/ireport-designer-getting-started

I wish that can help you good luck.

Comment: i will also suggest go with "jasper"

Comment: Ok . Thanks. I came across Jodreports. You provide a .odt file with variable using dollar sign and then use libreoffice to convert odt to pdf. This solution is good only if i have libre office install on the server. Do you happen to know a converter from odt to pdf?